# how to declare a initialized array in javascript, but also having extra property?

Tags: javascript

I have a array declared like this:

```
var test = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
];

test.extraProperty = 'extra';

console.log(test);
    console.log(test[0]); // correct, return 'one'
```

Is there a possibility to declare this initialized array at once (having extra property) but sill remain a array object? Like this:

```
var test = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
].extraProperty = 'extra';
```

Comment: it is possible, but hardly a good idea.

Comment: why not? since is it possible to add property in the first place, why not be able to declare like this at once? I may need to have array derivate object :)

Comment: if you have a derived array class, then something like `test = new MyArray([1,2,3], 'extra')` would be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
let test = Object.assign([
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
], {extraProperty: 'extra'});
console.log(test);
console.log(test.extraProperty);
```

Answer (score -3):

also can run like

```js
var test = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
];
test.extraProperty='extra';
console.log("Execute by .");
console.log(test);
console.log(test.extraProperty);
console.log(" ");
console.log("Execute as array");
console.log(test[0]);
console.log(test[1]);
console.log(test[2]);
console.log(test['extraProperty']);
```

but what you are trying is not possible,
so go with this approach.

Comment: Isn't that just what OP already has?